# How to reduce the size of HTTP response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server, localhost

I am more from a 8086 background who has happened to develop Flutter apps and I am completely new to understanding how a server is set up.

Here's my code snippet:

```
const http = require('http');

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  res.end('Welcome to Hello World');
  console.log(res)
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(707);
```

I tried printing the value of `res` and got an entire eternity of information...

Is this actually the amount of information being sent while visiting a website?

Is there any way to reduce the size of the `res`(ponse)?

Will I have to use some other protocol if it isn't possible to reduce the size of the request?

Also, the localhost takes time to respond after responding to 3-4 times...Is there any specific reason for it.

For now, I'm just trying to send a string as a response.

Please help me in improving my question if it is too vague. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I guess you have to start by reading the docs

Comment: Which docs precisely?

Comment: This https://nodejs.org/api/http.html should answer many of your questions

Comment: Are you trying to say that that information was sent by the NodeJS library and the response be smaller in size if I write it by myself using plain JS? Can I create a server from scratch without NodeJS?

Comment: No, you need the `http` library at least. I'd advice to use https://expressjs.com/ which is a bit less low level. The response object contains a bunch of properties and methods to manipulate the response, what you need is https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback

Comment: Is there some specific reason for it or will it be a lot of work (ofc, it should be)? Maybe a lot of situations could go unhandled...

Comment: The `http` library allow to handle the response as a stream, which give very fine grained options, but will likely be useless for most cases. express.js allows thinks like `res.send(...)` which allows to send a full body

Comment: My main objective was to actually create a real-time map that highlights COVID-19 cases across the world in real-time

Comment: You're supposed to try things, and ask questions on specific things if you're having problems not already answered on StackOverflow